# How to specify which unordered list to display with jQuery toggle

Tags: php, jquery, css

Hello I am trying to use the jQuery toggle function just to change a ul display state from:

```
display: none;
```

to

```
display: block;
```

and this works however I am receiving the information from the database and with jQuery toggle it is showing all of the information not specifically from category id in which i click on

Here's what I have so far:

```html
<section id="categories-wrapper">
  <div class="cat-center">
    <?php foreach($categories as $cat) { ?>
    <?php if($cat['parent_id'] < 1) { ?>
    <li>
      <a href="#!"><img src="media/categories/<?php echo $cat['image']; ?>"></a>
      <ul>
        <?php
$childCategories = $objCatalogue->getChildCategories($cat['id']);
?>
        <?php foreach($childCategories as $childCat) { ?>
        <li><?php echo $childCat['name']; ?></li>
        <?php } ?>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php } ?>
  </div>
</section>
```

the js code:

```
$('.cat-center li').click(function() {
    event.stopPropagation();
    $('.cat-center li ul').toggle('blind');
});
```

Now with the jQuery toggle when i click on the first link it shows the information from the other link as well, but with CSS using the hover command to just change display to block it works. Could someone please advise on what I am doing wrong.

Comment: It's always nice to post a jsfiddle for people to immediately check and give you feedback on.

Comment: Also are you trying to toggle a class or are you trying to toggle the jquery's  visibility animation?

Comment: First of all, your HTML is invalid, because it is missing the outer UL.

Comment: @A.Lau yes i am toggling jquery's visibility animation and it is working fine but it is also display the other drop down list but with css i dont have this issue when you the css hover effect

Comment: And then you of course don’t want to select _all_ elements that match `.cat-center li ul`, but only that inside the clicked item. So use $(this), and navigate to the proper element from there, f.e. using .find()

Comment: @CBroe thank you for answering, would it be possible to show me how as I do not seem to understand exactly what you are telling me to do, thanks again friend

Comment: `$(this).find('ul').toggle('blind');`

Comment: @CBroe cheers mate this gets the job done however now while the drop down is open and i click on the other category it over laps the two instead of closing the previous opened one and displaying the the currently clicked on drop down, thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your `$('.cat-center li ul').toggle('blind');`

to

```
$('.cat-center li').click(function() {
    event.stopPropagation();
    if ($(this).find('ul').is(":visible"))
    {
        $(this).find('ul').hide(500);
    }
    else
    {
      $('.cat-center li ul').hide(500);
      $(this).find('ul').toggle('blind');
    }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/m6jLo547/

Comment: doing this will hide my categories list and will not toggle the ul. I am trying to show and hide what is underneath each category link not the category itself, thank you for helping me out

Comment: Changed it. Try the `find`, if that's what you're after.

Comment: yes this works just like CBroe advised me to do as well, but now while I have one drop down open if i click the other category the previous category that was open still stays open, please tell me how i can close the other drop down when the new one is clicked, thanks for your help

Comment: Could add a `$('.cat-center li ul').hide();` before toggling the blind so that everything is definitely closed before opening.

Comment: perfect now one more thing left to do. If i click the opened category again it does not close it, thank you so much

Comment: It does a little weird reopening thing though, so you might want something to check if it's already open then just return if it is so nothing happens.

Comment: Look at the jsfiddle, tell me if anything else is missing. PS, it will behave funny at first because everything is visible.

Comment: if i told you i love you right now, would you believe me?. Thank you so much friend, thank you!!!

Comment: Good to be helpful